# FTL Perspective

Tags: technology, space, space-travel

Assuming that a method is discovered to travel FTL in normal space and assuming that one could observe the departure planet visually and/or monitor its radio waves, would the observer see history in reverse? If so what would be the implications of such a circumstance? How would this affect the moral of those traveling FTL?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not asking about how a world could be built, but instead asking for assumptions on physical phenomena (physics) without any prior assumptions being made by the OP. For this to be worldbuilding please can you specify more about how you intend this FTL mechanism to work in your world, and adjust your question about morale/visuals accordingly.

Comment: I agree that this is off-topic. I don't know if it's good for Physics Stack Exchange because this flat-out contradicts the laws of nature (although it might be), so perhaps asking in the Physics chat room about whether or not this would be appropriate there would be a good idea.

Comment: If you travelled exactly the speed of light, you wouldn't be able to observe anything because of special relativity, you'd be frozen in time. Since special relativity also states it's impossible to go faster than light (or even at the speed of light), I would think no one can even theorise what you would "see" (that's if if you'd be able to see / observe anything at all) if you did. It's pretty all speculation / making stuff up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would see nothing at all.
For you to see anything, photons need to hit your eye. Since you are faster than the photons following you, obviously they don't hit you.
It might be, though, that when you look away from the planet you are leaving, that you catch up with the photons that left the planet before, thus providing you with the image you expected.
Obviously that would require no space ship in the way. Also, at the speed at which you are leaving, the image will shrink at a rate that should leave you with nothing to observe in more or less no time at all.

Comment: Would the  same be true of radio signal? If you'd be able to capture those signals would you be able see the broadcast of earth in a reverse fashion? Would those dim at the same rate?

Comment: @GabeRuiz i assue yes, since the same rules apply there.

Answer (score 0):

How would you see something if you are faster than the light emitting from it?

To the FTL observer (if the receive some form of FTL transmission), it will look as if everything on that planet moves in fast-forward. I don't know why they should see history in reverse...
I guess technically, if you intercept a message in reverse than you will read the message in reverse but that's a huge long-shot - in a few words: it's all going to be garbled and blurred, if you even manage to pick it up somehow.

Morally, they might initially think: "wow, look how short life actually is" and that might affect their view on life.
But after a while, they will get biased and feel that their life is long because other peoples lives is so short. So, they would now consider life (their own life) to be long and might have a different view on life.

I mean, morally, you can do whatever you want with it. Humans are not morally homogenic! There are people who think suicide-bombing in a major city in Europe is moral, so...

Comment: The light has been emitted from before your departure? When observing a star from 10 light years away are you not observing the light emitted 10 years ago?

Comment: If you are observing the departure planet as you depart, you are not looking at the light that was emitted from before your departure.